# Extra characters on the end of replaced text

Tags: java, php, regex, pcre

In PHP and Java, I applied `/^[^\pL]*|[^\pL]*$/` to ‍‍‍`-A-` and I got `*A**`. I applied a symmetric pattern and got an asymmetric result! Why?  I wonder why its output is not `*A*`?

Pattern says that every thing except letter in the end of string should be replaced by `*`, it's also greedy and should replace all non-letter stuff together.

Alos note in RegexBuddy I get `*A*` that is what I expect.

**Update:** I simplified the question to focus my main concern.

Answer (score 27):

```
#^[^\pL]+|[^\pL]+$#u
```

Replace `*` with `+`. Using `*` in combination with `$` doesn't quite work as one would expect. In a bizarre consequence of how the regex engine works, `X*$` will find *two* matches for `X*`. Using `+` fixes it.

#### Explanation

```
[^\pL]*$
```

Let's look at this part of the regex, the part that's not working as expected. Why does it put two `*`'s at the end of some of the strings?

1. Consider the third example string `---A---` after the first set of dashes have been replaced:

   ```
   *A---$
   ```
2. The regex engine finds a match for the regex here:

   ```
   *A---$
     ^
   ```
3. And replaces `"---"` with an asterisk:

   ```
   *A*$
     ^
   ```
4. It then moves its internal cursor to the right of the replacement string.

   ```
   *A*$
      ^
   ```
5. It starts at this cursor position and looks for another match. And it finds one! It finds `""`—the empty string! `""` consists of 0-or-more non-letters (`[^\pL]*`), and it's anchored at the end of the string (`$`), so it's a valid match. It's found the empty string, sure, but that's allowed.

   It's unexpected because it's matched the `$` anchor yet again. Isn't that wrong? It shouldn't match `$` again, should it? Well, actually, it should, and does. It can match `$` again because `$` isn't an actual character in the input string—it's a zero-width assertion. It doesn't get "used up" by the first replacement. `$` is allowed to match twice.
6. And hence, it "replaces" the empty string `""` with an asterisk. This is why you end up with two asterisks.

   ```
   *A**$
      ^
   ```
7. If the regex engine returned to step 4, it would find yet another empty string and add yet another asterisk. Conceptually speaking, there are an infinite number of empty strings there. To avoid this the engine doesn't allow the next match to start at the same position as the previous one. This rule keeps it from entering an infinite loop.

Comment: @PHPst I'm not following. What did I ignore?

Comment: @PHPst Can you tell me which part of my explanation you don't follow (or don't agree with)?

Comment: @PHPst he ignored nothing. Your string is matched twice by `[^\pL]*$`. Once with '---' that is replaced. And one with '' just afterwards. The same reason your 'A' becomes '*A'.

Comment: @JohnKugelman You ignored greediness of RegEx. The replace action should occurs after third dash ---A---|.Characters following A should be replaced as a whole by '*'. I do not get how your answer show the unexpected replacement.

Comment: @PHPst your regex will match the `---` after your *A*. As a matter of fact, after the replacement, the pointer is still right after the last dash, but BEFORE the end of the string. And your regex also matches this emplacement. (The same reason /$/ is a regex that allows to insert content at the end of a string).

Comment: One thing to add: The reason it doesn't match a third time, is because  the previous match was empty. The engine doesn't allow the next match to start at the same position in this case, because then all the following matches would all also start there. It would get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @MarkusJarderot Oh, yes, excellent! I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Correct regex would be like this:

```
$arr = preg_replace('#^[^\pL]+|[^\pL]+$#','*', 
           array('A','-A-','---A---','-+*A*+-','------------A------------'));
```

Note `+` instead of `*`. This will give output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => *A*
    [2] => *A*
    [3] => *A*
    [4] => *A*
)
```

PS: Note that first element will remain unchanged due to the fact that there is no **non-alpha** character before and after A.

Comment: @didierc: Pls see note in my answer about first element.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is about behavior of above regex, not another one!

Answer (score 2):

**Give this a run:**
An explanation is given, both, after the code, and within the body of the code -- as comments.

```
<?php
class String
{
    private $str;
    public function __construct($str)
    {
        $this->str=$str;
    }
    public function replace($regex,$replacement)
    {
        return preg_replace($regex,$replacement,$this->str);
    }
}

function String($str)
{
    return new String($str);
}

echo String('A')->replace('/^[^\pL]*|[^\pL]*$/','*').'<br />';//Outputs *A*
 //Why does this output *A* and not A?
 //Because it successfully matches an empty string
 //The easiest way to test for the presence of an empty string is like so:
echo String('A')->replace('//','*').'<br />';//Outputs *A*
 //The engine begins by placing its internal pointer before the string like so:
 // A
 //^
 //It then tests the regular expression for the empty string ""
 //Most regular expressions will fail this test. But in our case matches it successfully.
 //Since we are preforming a search and replace the "" will get replaced by a "*" character
 //Then the internal pointer advances to the next character after its successful match
 // A
 // ^
 //It tests our regular expression for the A character and it fails.
 //Since we are performing a search and replace the searched "A" portion remains unchanged as "A"
 //The internal pointer advances to the next character
 // A
 //  ^
 //It tests our regular expression for the empty string ""
 //Again, most regular expressions will fail this test. But since ours successfully matched it,
 //The "" portion will get replaced by "*"
 //The engine then returns our output:
 //*A*
echo '<hr />';
 //If we wanted to replace the A character too, we'd do this:
echo String('A')->replace('/|A/','*').'<br />';//Outputs ***
 //Or we could do:
echo String('A')->replace('/.*?/','*').'<br />';//Outputs ***
 //Thus we see for a 1 character string the engine will test for the empty spaces "" before and after the character as well
 //For a 19 character string it tests for all the gaps between each character like so:
echo String('19 character string')->replace('//','*').'<br />';//Outputs *1*9* *c*h*a*r*a*c*t*e*r* *s*t*r*i*n*g*
 //For an empty string it would match once successfully like so:
echo String('')->replace('//','*').'<br />';//Outputs *
```

`echo String('A')->replace('/^[^\pL]*|[^\pL]*$/','*');//Outputs *A*`
Why does the above output `*A*` and not `A`?
Because this regular expression will **successfully** match against an empty string `""`.
The same behavior is observed using an empty regular expression, like so:
`echo String('A')->replace('//','*');//Outputs *A*`
I will now **explain** *why* the regular expression *engine* implementation is producing these strange results. Afterwards you will understand that they aren't so strange at all, but actually the correct behavior.
The engine begins by placing its **internal pointer** before the string like so:

```
  A
_ _ _
^
```

Since the pointer points to the empty string `""`, it then tests it against our regular expression.
Most regular expressions will fail this test because the minimum amount of characters needed to satisfy a regular expression is usually one or more. But in our case the match is **successful** because 0 characters is a valid match against our regular expression.
Since we are preforming a search and replace, the `""` will be replaced by the `"*"` character.
Then the **internal pointer** advances to the **next character** after its successful match:

```
  A
_ _ _
  ^
```

It tests our regular expression for the `"A"` character and it **fails**.
Since we are performing a search and replace, the searched `"A"` portion remains unchanged as `"A"`
The **internal pointer** advances to the **next character**:

```
  A
_ _ _
    ^
```

It tests our regular expression for the empty string `""`
Again, most regular expressions will fail this test.
But since our regular expression **successfully** matches it, the `""` portion will get replaced by `"*"`
The *engine* then **finishes** looping through our string `"A"` and **returns** our output: `"*A*"`

If we wanted to replace the A character too, we'd do this:
`echo String('A')->replace('/|A/','*');//Outputs ***`
Or we could do:
`echo String('A')->replace('/.*?/','*').'<br />';//Outputs ***`
Thus we see for a 1 character string the engine will test for `""` before and after the character as well.
For a 19 character string it tests for all the gaps between each character like so:
`echo String('19 character string')->replace('//','*');`
`//Outputs *1*9* *c*h*a*r*a*c*t*e*r* *s*t*r*i*n*g*`
For an empty string it would match once successfully like so:
`echo String('')->replace('//','*');//Outputs *`

That concludes my explanation. To fix your regular expression, do as previously suggested and use:
`/^[^\pL]+|[^\pL]+$/`
That will make the minimum amount of characters needed to satisfy the regular expression one, thus working around the unwanted behavior.

As a last remark, if anyone is wondering what `\pL` does in regular expressions, it basically means: match any letter-like character (as opposed to a number or symbol). It is explained here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[^\pL]*|[^\pL]*$/  
['A','-A-','---A---','-+*A*+-','------------A------------']
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question or the regex, but it looks like it matches one of two options

Option 1: It matches `/^` the beginning of a newline or string. it then matches a character that is not a letter zero or more times

so theoretically `-A`, `=A`, `-` , ````` =-+_+_==-=~````~!@#$A `````, or even `=-+_+_==-=~~!@#` would match this.

Option 2: it matches something that is not a letter zero or more times, then matches the end of a string or line